# inject resolve into toParams on $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, resolve

I have a config file which contains a state that looks like the following:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '?data',
    abstract: true,
    resolve: {
        data: ['MyModel', '$stateParams', function (MyModel, $stateParams) {
            return MyModel.getData($stateParams);
        }]
    }
});
```

and then a module file that looks like this:

```
App.module.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
```

where `toParams` would return `object{data:undefined}`. I know that the resolve works and should have data. How do I correctly pass the resolve from my state into the `$stateChangeStart` and then access it?

I have tried injecting my data resolve manually into my module file, but it returns undefined. I have tried setting the `params` attribute to see if that was the way to go:

```
resolve: {
        data: ['MyModel', '$stateParams', function (MyModel, $stateParams) {
            return MyModel.getData($stateParams);
        }]
    },
params: { 
    'foo':'bar', // this would be available in toParams 
    'data': //can i put my data here? 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply be able to inject `MyModel` into your run function, and read it the same way you read it inside your resolve process. Example run function *(assumes your `getData` function returns a promise)*:

```
App.module.run(function($rootScope, MyModel) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
        // get the same data your resolve is using (you can also pass in toParams or the like)
        MyModel.getData(toParams).then(function(data){
            // do something with your data here inside $stateChangeStart
        });
    });
});
```

This is what makes injection great, you simply inject something when you want to use it.

Comment: is this not defeating the object of having a resolve? or have i missed something

Comment: The usual purpose of a resolve is to ensure certain promises have completed before loading the route and controller. I am not exactly sure why you want your resolve data in $stateChangeStart, but my solution works.

Comment: in my stateChangeStart i want to only allow a route to change if my promise is resolved, as the routes depend on the data. So if i inject it manually as you suggest i'm not sure that is confirming that my resolve has resolved if that makes sense. Your method does work though in terms of getting me the data i want.

Comment: That sounds like the purpose of resolve, and you don't need to use $stateChangeStart at all. You just inject the resolved value into your controller, but if the promise fails the route will not change.